# Checking correctness of function call expression

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, type-traits

`std::result_of` computes the return type of a calling expression at compile time.

As [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) says, if the call is ill-formed the instantation of `std::result_of` results in a compilation error. But suppose that what we need is to check if the call is well formed, before getting the result type.

**Is there any way to write a trait that checks if a calling expression is well-formed?**

Something like:

```
template<typename F , typename... ARGS>
struct is_valid_call : public impl::is_valid_call<F,typelist<ARGS...>>
{};

namespace impl
{
    struct sfinae_result{};

    template<typename F , typename ARGS , typename ENABLED = sfinae_result>
    struct is_valid_call;

    template<typename F , typename... ARGS>
    struct is_valid_call<F,typelist<ARGS...>,
                         decltype( std::declval<F>()(std::declval<ARGS>()...) )
                        > : 
        public std::true_type
    {};

    template<typename F , typename... ARGS>
    struct is_valid_call<F,typelist<ARGS...>,sfinae_result> : 
        public std::false_type
    {};
}
```

**EDIT:** Of course the solution posted [doesn't work](http://ideone.com/yuXO8R)

Comment: @jrok of course for a real implementation I should take care of function pointers, functors, and lambdas. But suppose that are functors only, to simplify the question (The solution is the same, isn't? Only more cases). My intention is to use such trait in SFINAE contexts, specifically (For example) to check if a given transformation function is applicable to an specific type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's something that works:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename F, typename... Args>
struct is_valid_call {
private:
    template<typename FF, typename... AA>
    static constexpr auto check(int) ->
    decltype( std::declval<FF>()(std::declval<AA>()...), std::true_type());

    template<typename FF, typename... AA>
    static constexpr std::false_type check(...);
public:
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(check<F, Args...>(0)){};
};

#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
   printf("%d", int (is_valid_call<decltype(&puts), const char*>::value));
   printf("%d", int (is_valid_call<decltype(&puts), double>::value));
}
```

Output: `10`

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use the comma evaluation trick and not just write the `declval` on the template?

Comment: The reason is me not thinking very much about it :) Yes, that would probably be cleaner.

Comment: @Manu343726 Wait, on the second reading, I'm not sure I understand you :)

Comment: I commonly put that sort of things on the template (Like `std::enable_if` on a default template parameter, for example). Thats why the comma trick disappointed me. My question is: Is that neccesary to make it work or is just the way you thought it?

Comment: And that's probably what's bitten you - your implentation doesn't work because second specialization of `impl::is_valid_call` is more specialized and always gets picked. It think, at least - it's late sunday evening and my head isn't all that clear anymore... I also don't see why would you be disappointed - it's your good old expression SFINAE.

Comment: +1 Nice solution.  A closely related (and useful) trait is what I call `invokable`.  It allows all 5 bullets from 20.9.2/p1 (`is_valid_call` allows only the 5th bullet).  This expanded trait covers (for example) the arguments you can construct a `std::thread`  or `std::function` with, including pointers to member functions, and pointers to member data.  Imho sufficiently challenging and useful to warrant standardization.